# Yii framework: Customize Search

Tags: search, yii, full-text-search, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yii framework: Using data from related Active Record models for searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031514/yii-framework-using-data-from-related-active-record-models-for-searching)

Yii framework provide searching list of models based on the search/filter conditions.

It provide this functionality for searching content on one table only.

But i needs to perform this functionality based for two tables.

I have table called User and Order.

I have generated search functionality based on Order table. But i want to integrate user's name in to order search.

Answer (score 1):

In your Order Model :

```
...

public function relations(){
    return array(
                 ...
        'user0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId'),
                 ...
    );
}
....


 public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            ...
    $criteria->compare('userId',$this->userId);
            ...
}

...
```

At your view/order/admin :

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'deviceinfo-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            ...
            array(            
                'name'=>'userId',
                'value'=>'$data->user0->name',
                'filter'=>CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
            ),

            ...
        ),
    )); ?>
```

And try this code
I thing This is help for you

Comment: i have tried what you have mentioned, it gives me drop down list of relational entries. but i want to do something which is explained in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028933/yii-framework-what-does-this-jquery-line-of-code-means