# Yii framework: what does this JQuery line of code means

Tags: php, jquery, search, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yii framework: Using data from related Active Record models for searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031514/yii-framework-using-data-from-related-active-record-models-for-searching)

Yii provide advanced search functionality under admin page.

This picture explain my question well.

[image]

This functionality shown on the picture is carried out by following code sample.

```
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('order-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
```

There is a form with  class attribute named `search-form` where we provide search criteria. Based on the search criteria, it update the grid view called order which is generated by following code sample.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'order-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'order_create_date',
        'price',
        'bank_account_number',
        'hardwaredetail_Id',
        'user_id',
        'user.name',
        'user.email',
        ),
}
```

Order table has a relationship with user table. i want to perform search functionality on user's name and email address. But Advanced search functionality Auto generate code only for search on order table. i am trying to customize advanced search to be able to search on relational data as well

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super sure what you're asking or if it's possible, but let me try and explain what is going on in your current code eample:

```
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('order-grid', {
         data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
```

1. When you submit the form by hitting the search button jQuery stops the form from submitting.
2. Instead, it will submit it using the $.fn.yiiGridView.update function.
3. $(this).serialize() takes all of the data from the form and puts it into a format that's easy for the server to read.

As for the other code sample it just creates the HTML for the form with an id of 'order-grid'.

Now, on to what you're hoping to do instead. I've looked for some examples and docs about the `$.fn.yiiGridView.update`, which might be able to shed light on this. Here's what I've got:

1. http://tech.ldg.me/yii-php-framework-snippets
2. http://code.google.com/p/zii/source/browse/trunk/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js?r=65
3. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Sorry, I don't know more about the Yii framework and good luck!